# cert.der: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, certificate

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("cert.der"));
```

> 09-10 20:59:02.526: I/System.out(11341): ssdada cert.der: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am using android with eclipse. I have cert.der on application level, under my src folder..and under the same folder as well as my Class that am calling the above code from.
Where shall I add it still?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the directory structure of where the cert.der is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it in the `raw` or `assets`. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

> raw/
>   Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>
> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.